# Laravel - Rate Limiting specific API routes

Tags: php, laravel, api

I'm currently working on a Laravel-driven site which is powered by two separate servers, an API server and a public web server (both running Laravel).

The API has a number of routes which are used to validate availability of certain key terms, such as email address and URL slug. These routes are called via AJAX to check the database, and are triggered on keypresses.

As can be expected with the AJAX request being triggered many times a minute, the API throws a "Too many requests" error. I know this can be fixed with increasing the request limit, however I only want to do this for a two routes, not all of them.

How can I disable the rate limit on a single API route?

Here is one of the routes, it's pretty standard:

```
Route::post('/email/is-available', function(Request $request) {

    ...

})->middleware('my_own_api_key_checking_middleware');
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I would use https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Throttle that comes with a route middleware.

Comment: Great, thanks for this @namelivia, any ideas how I would disable the rate limit rather than increase it?

Comment: Yeah, comment out the `throttle` line on `app/Http/Kernel.php`. By the way, the package is integrated on the latest versions of laravel framework by default. Let me elaborate a bit more as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are recieving the too many requests message because Laravel is appying the throttle middleware to all api routes by default, to disable it go to `app/Http/Kernel.php` and delete or comment the `throttle` array entry from the property `$middlewareGroups`, this will disable throttling for every route on the group.
Now on your routes file add it to the route you want:

```
->middleware('throttle:240,1');
```

Where the first number is the limit of requests and the second one is the time.

Comment: Great, thanks for this answer! To disable the throttling for a single route, would I have to disable for all and re-apply the limit to all routes I want the throttling to be turned on?

Comment: Oh, is this using https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Throttle ? If so, don't forget to include in your answer :)

Comment: You can create a middleware group and put all your routes but the one you want not to throttle in the group.